# Using Webgl on openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, webgl, openlayers-3

I have seen two examples of using Webgl in openlayers 3.

[Icon-sprite-webgl](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/icon-sprite-webgl.html)

[Symbol-atlas-webgl](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/symbol-atlas-webgl.html)

both of those examples doesnt help me much to intergrate Tiles and Vector Data like points, and lines.

there is any way of using Webgl for draw Points and Lines? and also have a tiles in the background of the map?

Comment: [WebGL will draw whatever you program it to draw](http://webglfundamentals.org). If you're asking for a library, asking for libraries is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Note that OpenLayers 3 currently only supports points for WebGL, and that is shown in the two examples that you are linking to.